# Bash shell OR'ed comparison of strings fails

Tags: string, bash

This is similar to posts I have googled but I can't find an exact answer. I am trying to compare two strings ORed with another two string comparison:

```
elif [[ "$2" != "append" ]] || [[ "$2" != "replace" ]]
```

But the test fails even if append or replace is typed. Strangely enough, a single comparison works:

```
elif [[ "$2" != "append" ]]
```

So I know the problem is with the OR part, but am unable to fix the problem.

Comment: It should be `elif [[ "$2" != "append" || "$2" != "replace" ]]`

Comment: what are you looking for ` [[ "$2" != "append" ]] || [[ "$2" != "replace" ]]` to return when `$2` is `"append"`? True or False?

Comment: @khachik `||` is valid both inside and outside the brackets. That's not the problem.

Comment: I am looking for the expression to do the elif statements if $2 is neither "append" OR "replace"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
elif [[ "$2" != "append" ]] && [[ "$2" != "replace" ]]
```

Every string will pass the test if you use `||`. There is no string that is equal to both `append` and `replace`.

> I am looking for the expression to do the elif statements if $2 is neither "append" OR "replace".

Translating directly from English to code sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. Here it doesn't. You're really looking for a check that `$2` is neither "append" NOR "replace". And there's no NOR operator. There is an AND operator, as in: check that `$2` isn't "append" AND that it isn't "replace". That's a sentence that *is* translatable.

Comment: Eureka! That works! Thank you - I think I tried everything but &&

Answer (score 3):

The conditioning is probably wrong.

`[[ "$2" != "append" ]] || [[ "$2" != "replace" ]]` would always be true.

`[[ "$2" != "append" ]]` would always be true if `[[ $2 == replace ]]` or if `$2` has any other value besides `append`.

Answer (score 0):

Also I suggest you to put it inside the brackets:

```
elif [[ $2 != 'append' && $2 != 'replace' ]]
```

Or you can use extglob to omit && completely:

```
shopt -s extglob
...

elif [[ $2 != @(append|replace) ]]
```

It seems like that is exactly what you expect!

Note that you don't have to quote the left side inside `[[ ]]` brackets.